# Finding the set of all possible values of a function similar to Nesbitt's Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, functional-inequalities

> Let $x,$ $y,$ $z$ be positive real numbers. Find the set of all possible values of
> $$f(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{x + y} + \frac{y}{y + z} + \frac{z}{z + x}.$$

This seems extremely similar to Nesbitt's inequality, in which I did some reasearch on this problem to find. Nesbitt's states that for positive real $a, b, c,$ then $$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}.$$ However I note that the function stated in the problem isn't in the same orientation to apply Nesbitt's, and just similar. I'm stumped on making any progression on this problem, as I've tried combining the denominators to form one big fraction as well as substituting variables to try clearing denominators. I would appreciate some help to start this problem.

Comment: Is there any reason why $f$ wouldn't map onto $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: One thought for you : imagine $y$ and $z$ are *fixed* positive real numbers. Which values of $x$ then maximize or minimize $f(x,y,z)$? Think of the derivative (if you can use calculus) else substitute a few values and get a clue of what things look like when only one variable moves.@tomasliam $f \leq 3$ because each fraction is $\leq 1$, the denominator is bigger than numerator in each one. That is what differentiates it from Nesbitt. Also note that $f \geq 1$, the hint being that at least two of the fractions will be bigger than $\frac 12$.

Comment: I'm not that familar with calculus, but I will try to substitude some values given your conditions and see if I can find any patterns.

Comment: Did you try rearrangement inequality?

Comment: @Anand  I tried. It does not help.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well, it works for the case $x\geq y\geq z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $1 < f(x,y,z) < 2.$ Indeed, because
$$\frac{x}{x+y} \geqslant \frac{x}{x+y+z}.$$
Equality occur when $x = 0$ or $z = 0.$

Therefore
$$f(x,y,z) \geqslant \frac{x+y+z}{x+y+z} = 1.$$
But $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers, so $f(x,y,z) > 1.$

Another
$$\frac{x}{x+y} < \frac{x+z}{x+y+z},$$
equivalent to
$$\frac{yz}{(x+y)(x+y+z)}\geqslant 0.$$
Equality occur when $yz=0.$ So
$$f(x,y,z) < \frac{2(x+y+z)}{x+y+z}=2.$$

Comment: Oh, I see. You can manipulate and rearrange the equation to end up with this outcome.

Comment: See also: [IMO 1974/5.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1974_IMO_Problems#Problem_5)